# TYPO3 v9 routeEnhancers for multiple objects

Tags: typo3, url-routing

I built an extension where it is possible to pass multiple "lines" via a checkboxes to the controller.

Therefore the called url that is generated and could look like that if you check three boxes:

`my.site.com/?tx_plugin['lines']['0']=32&tx_plugin['lines']['1']=53&tx_plugin['lines']['2']=8`

In order to have readable urls I would like to use routeEnhancers on that url but I don't find anything in the documentation that explains how to interact with multiple objects.
Documentation ->
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/SiteHandling/ExtendingSiteConfig.html

What is the correct way to handle urls like that?

Answer (score 0):

That is possible. You dig up the wrong documentation, though. Try https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Routing/AdvancedRoutingConfiguration.html

You probably want to use the (Extbase) Plugin Enhancer.
Then take care about your aspects. For your use case have a look at the StaticRangeMapper.

```
routePath: /{a}/{b}
aspects:
  a: ...
  b: ...
```